# htaccess redirection from a folder to another and adding file extension

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working on a website redesign, that is sort of a profile directory. The current website has a directory called "conference" and inside that folder, there's all the persons profiles.
So the URL structure of the current website is

domain.com/conference/firstname-lastname/

The new website I'm working on has a different URL structure.
It will be:

domaine.com/profile/firstname-lastname.html

firstname-lastname being replaced by the first name and last name of each persons profile on the site (obviously).

So instead of the "conference" folder, it becomes the "profile" folder, and then instead of a the page acting like a folder in the URL (firstname-lastname/), it will keep the same name, but needs to add ".html".

How can I do that with htaccess without having to make a 301 redirect on all profiles one by one? (there's around 100 profiles..that would take way too long)

Here's the htaccess code I've started with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^conference/(.*) profile/ [R=301,L]
```

Is that how I should do it? And I'm not sure about the replace "firstname-lastname/" with "firstname-lastname.html" (adding html to all the names).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect

- /conference/foo-bar/

to

- /profile/foo-bar.html

You can use the following rule in `/.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^conference/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ /profile/$1-$2.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks! And this will work with whatever name file the "foo-bar.html" has? So that it would work if there's a page named "foo2-bar2.html", or "mac-book.html", and so on? That's what the "$1" and "$2" are for? Thanks again